# How can I delete a file created and opened with Perl's IO::File and XML::Writer?

Tags: xml, perl, file-io

So I'm running through a list of things and have code that creates an *.xml* files with [IO::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html) called `$doc`, then I make a new writer with `XML::Writer(OUTPUT => $doc)`. More code runs and I build a big XML file with [XML::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Writer). Then, near the end of the file, I find out if I need this file at all. If I do need it, I just:

```
 $writer->end(); $doc->close();
```

but if I don't need it, what should I enter to just delete all data I've stored/saved and move onto the next file? I tried `unlink($docpath)` (before and after `$doc->close()`), the file was not deleted.

Comment: A minimal but complete example of what you are trying to do would help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unlink` will helpfully set `$!` and return a false value if no files were deleted. Try:

```
unlink $docpath or die "Can't delete $docpath: $!";
```

and you might gain some insight.

Comment: Ah, that dumped me something: Can't find file. Which is really weird because I'm using the exact same $docpath to declare the new file. What's up with that?

$docpath = "./test/blah_blah.xml";

$doc = new IO::File(">$docpath");

then the unlink statement like you have.

I even have print statements after declaring $docpath and before unlink, and they are exactly the same. Seriously, wtf?

Comment: Does your script change the working directory between creating the file and trying to delete it? What happens if you change it to an absolute path?

Comment: (working dir never changed)Ok, I sorta figured it out. What I actually did was write a method that had your unlink statement. sub deleteFile($path){unlink $path...} and then I called the method: deleteFile($docpath); This is when things broke. But when I just ran your statement where I put the method call, everything worked. So I must be missing something on declaring or calling subroutines. Do you happen to know what it is?

Comment: Yes, you are declaring the subroutine wrong. Arguments are passed in via the `@_` array. `sub deleteFile { my $file = $_[0]; unlink $file or die $!; }` should do it. You would have discovered this problem much sooner if you were running with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` on. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html for more.

Comment: ***Always*** run with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Always.